# How to add filename to archive if compressing using Gzip class?

Tags: c++, gzip, crypto++

I'm using Gzip to compress data before encryption.

```
Gzip gz;
gz.Put(file,size)
gz.MessageEnd();
gz.Get(file,gz.MaxRetrievable());
```

I want the created gzip file to include the original filename as metadata. How do i do this through the Crypto++ interface?

Comment: The Crypto++ wiki now has a page for Gzip, including the patch below. See [WIki page on Gzip](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gzip).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want the created gzip file to include the original filename as metadata. How do i do this through the Crypto++ interface?

You can't out-of-the-box. It appears to be a limitation of Crypto++. (But see below).

From [RFC 1952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) there's clearly a field for it:

```
  (if FLG.FNAME set)

     +=========================================+
     |...original file name, zero-terminated...| (more-->)
     +=========================================+
```

But Crypto++ does not allow you to set it (from [gzip.c source code](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/cryptopp/code/trunk/c5/gzip.cpp)):

```
void Gzip::WritePrestreamHeader()
{
    m_totalLen = 0;
    m_crc.Restart();

    AttachedTransformation()->Put(MAGIC1);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(MAGIC2);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(DEFLATED);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(0);       // general flag
    AttachedTransformation()->PutWord32(0); // time stamp
    byte extra = (GetDeflateLevel() == 1) ? FAST : ((GetDeflateLevel() == 9) ? SLOW : 0);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(extra);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(GZIP_OS_CODE);
}
```

And Crypto++ silently discards it if its present when its unzipping (`Gunzip` is the GZIP decompressor) (from [gzip.c source code](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/cryptopp/code/trunk/c5/gzip.cpp)):

```
void Gunzip::ProcessPrestreamHeader()
{
    ...

    if (flags & EXTRA_FIELDS)   // skip extra fields
    {
        word16 length;
        if (m_inQueue.GetWord16(length, LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER) != 2) throw HeaderErr();
        if (m_inQueue.Skip(length)!=length) throw HeaderErr();
    }

    if (flags & FILENAME)   // skip filename
        do
            if(!m_inQueue.Get(b)) throw HeaderErr();
        while (b);

    if (flags & COMMENTS)   // skip comments
        do
            if(!m_inQueue.Get(b)) throw HeaderErr();
        while (b);
}
```

---

You're the first person I recall asking for it in about 15 years, so its not a popular request :)

Here's how to modify the sources to add a filetime, filename and comment. You can find the patch on the Crypto++ wiki pages for [Gzip](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gzip) and [Gunzip](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gunzip). You can find the SVN diff on Pastebin at [Diff for Crypto++ gzip for filename and comment processing](http://pastebin.com/bE0qX42u). The fles are mostly the same, but the wiki is more current because its got some reset code in `Gzip::WritePoststreamTail`.

First, add the following protected members to the `Gzip` and `Gunzip` classes:

```
word32 m_filetime;
std::string m_filename;
std::string m_comment;
```

Second, add an initializer for `m_filetime` for each constructor (both `Gzip` and `Gunzip`). For example, here's one for one of the `Gzip` ctors:

```
Gzip(const NameValuePairs &parameters, BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL)
    : Deflator(parameters, attachment), m_filetime(0) {}
```

Third, add public setters to the `Gzip` class:

```
void SetFiletime(word32 filetime) { m_filetime = filetime; }
void SetFilename(const std::string& filename) { m_filename = filename; }
void SetComment(const std::string& comment) { m_comment = comment; }
```

Fourth, add public getters to the `Gunzip` class:

```
word32 GetFiletime() const { return m_filetime; }
const std::string& GetFilename() const { return m_filename; }
const std::string& GetComment() const { return m_comment; }
```

Fifth, change `Gzip::WritePrestreamHeader` to the following in the cpp file:

```
void Gzip::WritePrestreamHeader()
{
    m_totalLen = 0;
    m_crc.Restart();

    int flags = 0;
    if(!m_filename.empty())
        flags |= FILENAME;
    if(!m_comment.empty())
        flags |= COMMENTS;

    AttachedTransformation()->Put(MAGIC1);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(MAGIC2);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(DEFLATED);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put((byte)flags);    // general flag
    AttachedTransformation()->PutWord32(m_filetime, LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER);    // time stamp

    byte extra = (GetDeflateLevel() == 1) ? FAST : ((GetDeflateLevel() == 9) ? SLOW : 0);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(extra);        
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(GZIP_OS_CODE);

    if(!m_filename.empty())
        AttachedTransformation()->Put((const unsigned char*)m_filename.data(), m_filename.size() +1);

    if(!m_comment.empty())
        AttachedTransformation()->Put((const unsigned char*)m_comment.data(), m_comment.size() +1);
}
```

Sixth, change `Gzip::WritePoststreamTail` to the following in the cpp file:

```
void Gzip::WritePoststreamTail()
{
    SecByteBlock crc(4);
    m_crc.Final(crc);
    AttachedTransformation()->Put(crc, 4);
    AttachedTransformation()->PutWord32(m_totalLen, LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER);

    m_filetime = 0;

    m_filename.erase(0);
    m_filename.reserve(16);

    m_comment.erase(0);
    m_comment.reserve(32);
}
```

Seventh, change `Gunzip::ProcessPrestreamHeader` to the following in the cpp file:

```
void Gunzip::ProcessPrestreamHeader()
{
    m_length = 0;
    m_crc.Restart();

    m_filetime = 0;

    m_filename.erase(0);
    m_filename.reserve(16);

    m_comment.erase(0);
    m_comment.reserve(32);

    byte buf[6];
    byte b, flags;

    if (m_inQueue.Get(buf, 2)!=2) throw HeaderErr();
    if (buf[0] != MAGIC1 || buf[1] != MAGIC2) throw HeaderErr();
    if (!m_inQueue.Get(b) || (b != DEFLATED)) throw HeaderErr();     // skip CM flag
    if (!m_inQueue.Get(flags)) throw HeaderErr();
    if (flags & (ENCRYPTED | CONTINUED)) throw HeaderErr();
    if (m_inQueue.GetWord32(m_filetime, LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER) != 4) throw HeaderErr();
    if (m_inQueue.Skip(2)!=2) throw HeaderErr();    // Skip extra flags and OS type

    if (flags & EXTRA_FIELDS)   // skip extra fields
    {
        word16 length;
        if (m_inQueue.GetWord16(length, LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER) != 2) throw HeaderErr();
        if (m_inQueue.Skip(length)!=length) throw HeaderErr();
    }

    if (flags & FILENAME)   // extract filename
    {
        do
        {
            if(!m_inQueue.Get(b)) throw HeaderErr();
            if(b) m_filename.append( 1, (char)b );
        }
        while (b);
    }

    if (flags & COMMENTS)   // extract comments
    {
        do
        {
            if(!m_inQueue.Get(b)) throw HeaderErr();
            if(b) m_comment.append( 1, (char)b );
        }
        while (b);
    }
}
```

---

Here's how to use it:

```
try {

    Gzip zipper(new FileSink("gzip-test.gz", true));
    zipper.SetFilename("test-filename.txt");
    zipper.SetComment("This is a test of filenames and comments");

    string data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    zipper.Put( (unsigned char*) data.c_str(), data.size());
    zipper.MessageEnd();        
}
catch(CryptoPP::Exception& ex)
{
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

The compressed file name is `gzip-test.gz`. The original filename field in the header is `test-filename.txt`, and the comment in the header is `This is a test of filenames and comments`.

You can see it in action using a hex editor:

[image]

---

Here's how it works in practice with both `gzip -d` and the default archive extractor on Mac OS X: the embedded filename is ignored, and the file is saved using the archive filename less the `gz` extension:

[image]

I don't know if that's expected behavior or not since the filename member has something to do with preserving long filenames on filesystems that don't support them.

There's an open question on the behavior on Super User: [Is Gzip supposed to honor original filename for decompress?](https://superuser.com/q/859785/173513).

**EDIT**: thanks to Simon on Super User, one must use `gunzip -N <gz-file>` to extract using the original filename stashed away in the header.

---

For completeness, here's what a round trip looks like when writing the archive to an in-memory string rather than an on-disk file.

```
string s1, s2;
string data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

Gzip zipper(new StringSink(s1));
zipper.SetFilename("test-filename.txt");
zipper.SetComment("This is a test of filenames and comments");

zipper.Put( (unsigned char*) data.c_str(), data.size());
zipper.MessageEnd();

Gunzip unzipper(new StringSink(s2));
unzipper.Put( (unsigned char*) s1.data(), s1.size());
unzipper.MessageEnd();

cout << "Filename: " << unzipper.GetFilename() << endl;
cout << "Comment: " << unzipper.GetComment() << endl;
cout << "Data: " << s2 << endl;
```

It produces expected results.

---

There's an important caveat with the modifications above. The mods work well when the archive contains a single file. But *if* the stream contains multiple files, then the filetime, filename and comment will only be provided for the last filestream. If they are missing from the last filestream, then they will be empty in the getters.

The reason for the limitation has to do with the way Crypto++ pipelines are architected. In Crypto++, each stream is considered a message. You can call `NextMessage()` and get back the bytes in the stream. But the stream is a collection of unpacked bytes, and not a higher level structure that can accomodate the extra fields.

I'm pretty sure the fix for it is non-trivial. I believe it means that the `Gzip` compressor and `Gunzip` decompressor will need channels added so that you can retrieve the additional data, like the way you retrieve the cipher text (`DEFAULT_CHANNEL`) or authentication tag (`AAD_CHANNEL`) from an Authenticated Encryption filter.